# How to handle null in session variable of type int

Tags: c#, session, null

If the `session["Colindex"]` is null. It throws a error msg saying that Object reference not set to null.

```
int colid =(int) Session["ColIndex"];
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Use C# `??` null coalescing operator:

```
int colid = (int)(Session["ColIndex"] ?? 0);
```

This will set `colid` to the value in Session, or 0 if it's null.

Answer (score 2):

If the `Session["ColIndex"]` has yet to be created, then there is no value. As `Session` is a reference variable, there is no reference to the instance of the object on the heap which is why you are receiving the "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*" error. In other words, the Session variable was never assigned/created.

You'll need to test for null before casting your session:

```
if ( Session["ColIndex"] != null )
{
  int colid = (int)Session["ColIndex"];
  // do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what language this is for, but you probably need to test for null before casting to int.

Comment: Language is C#. The error msg is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"